# rails 2.3.2 project: Could not find RubyGem uuid (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a problems with launching a project on rails 2.3.2 
How can I setup my rails-environtment with rvm to normal work?
It's what my terminal says:

```
script/server
/Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.1/lib/rubygems-bundler/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:48: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.2 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem uuid (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
    from /Users/bmalets/Documents/ror_projects/bystroservis_old/config/environment.rb:23
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:111:in `run'
    from /Users/bmalets/Documents/ror_projects/bystroservis_old/config/environment.rb:9
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

When I try to install gems for my project, I have this one:

```
rake gems:install
/Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `trace_on': undefined method `end_with?' for "rake aborted!":String (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `map'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `trace_on'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:322:in `trace'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `display_error_message'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:169:in `standard_exception_handling'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/bin/rake:19
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
```

Comment: gem install rails -v 2.3.2

Comment: Rails 2.3.2
ruby  1.8.6 (2010-09-02 patchlevel 420) [i686-darwin11.4.2]
gems  1.3.7

Comment: can you print rails version ? which rails

Comment: $ which rails =>
/Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/bin/rails

Comment: $ rails -v =>
Rails 2.3.2

Comment: you need to use the right rake version for rails 2.3.2, gem uninstall rake and gem install rake -v=0.8.7

Comment: I have rake with this version in my gem list.
rails (2.3.2)
rake (0.8.7). It's not work :(

Comment: maybe it's good idea to uninstall all rubies with gems and install them again?

Comment: when you run again rake gems:install into the directory, what rake version is used ? because i see rake-10.0.3 into your logs.

Comment: problem is resolved. thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rvm @global do gem uninstall -ax rubygems-bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall rubygems and it help for me.